# backbone database search firing 4 times

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, promise, deferred, backbone.js-collections

I have some search functionality in my backbone application that queries a database via an API, but for some reason it fires 4 times (or atleast returns the results 4 times).

Here is my code,

**Collections**

```
    App.Collections.SearchableCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({},{  

    search: function(query, options) {
        var search = $.Deferred();
        options = options || {};
        var collection = new this([], options);
        collection.url = _.result(collection, 'url');

        var fetch = collection.fetch({
            data: {
                q: query
            }
        });

        fetch.done(_.bind(function(){
            Pops.EVENTS.trigger('search:done');
            search.resolveWith(this, [collection]);
        }, this));

        fetch.fail(function(){
            Pops.EVENTS.trigger('search:fail');
            search.reject();
        });

        return search.promise();
    }

});

App.Collections.ProjectSearch = App.Collections.SearchableCollection.extend({

    url: Pops.API_ROOT + '/search/projects',

});
```

**Views**

```
App.Views.GlobalResults = Backbone.View.extend({

el : '.ui-grid-list--results',

events: {
    "click .js-open-project" : "removeSearchView"
},

initialize: function() {
    this.addAll();
},

render: function() {
    var noResult = new Pops.Views.NoGlobalResult;

    this.$el.before(noResult.render().el);

    return this;
},

addAll: function() {
    if(this.collection.length > 0) {
        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
    } else {
        this.render();
    }
},

addOne: function(model) {
    var resultItem = new Pops.Views.GlobalResult({
        model:model
    });

    this.$el.append( resultItem.render().el );
},

removeSearchView: function(e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.ui-fullscreen').remove();
    }, 1000);

}
```

});

App.Views.NoGlobalResult = Backbone.View.extend({

```
className: 'ui-message-block',

template: _.template("<h5>No Results Found</h5><p>Sorry, we could not find any projects that matched your serach criteria.</p>"),

initialize: function() {

},

render: function() {

    this.$el.html( this.template() );

    return this;

}
```

});

App.Views.GlobalResult = Backbone.View.extend({

```
tagName : 'li',

className: 'ui-grid-list__item',

template: _.template( $('#tpl-project-list-item').html() ),

initialize: function() {

},

render: function() {
    var self = this;
    var pjCreatedDate  = moment( this.model.get('created_at'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' ) ;
    var userCreatedDate  = moment( Pops.Session.get('created_at'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' ) ;
    var oneWeekBeforeuserCreatedDate  = userCreatedDate.subtract(8, 'day') ;
    var giveNewTag  = pjCreatedDate.isAfter(oneWeekBeforeuserCreatedDate) && (typeof this.model.get('projectview') != 'undefined' && this.model.get('projectview').length === 0);

    if(this.model.get('project_manager') instanceof Backbone.Collection === false){

        this.model.set({'project_manager':new App.Collections.Users},{silent:true});

    }if(this.model.get('collaborators') instanceof Backbone.Collection === false){

        this.model.set({'collaborators':new App.Collections.Users},{silent:true});

    }if(this.model.get('organisations') instanceof Backbone.Model === false){

        var organisations  = this.model.get('organisations');
        this.model.set({'organisations':new Pops.Models.Organisation(organisations)},{silent:true});

    }if(this.model.get('user') instanceof Backbone.Model === false){

        var users  = this.model.get('user');
        this.model.set({'user':new Pops.Models.User(users)},{silent:true});

    }if(this.model.get('clients') instanceof Backbone.Model === false){

        var clients  = this.model.get('clients');
        this.model.set({'clients':new Pops.Models.Client(clients)},{silent:true});

    }


    var projectmanagers = this.model.get('project_manager').toJSON();
    var collaborators =  this.model.get('collaborators').toJSON();

    var collabs = projectmanagers.concat(collaborators);

    this.$el.html( this.template({
        project: this.model.toJSON(),
        newTag: giveNewTag,
        collaborators: collabs
    }));

    this.model.get('project_manager').each(function(model, i){

        if(i < 3) {
            var newUser = new Pops.Views.UserInitials({
                model:model
            });
            self.$('.ui-inline-list').append(newUser.render().el);
        }
    });

    this.model.get('collaborators').each(function(model, i){

        if(i < 3) {
            var newUser = new Pops.Views.UserInitials({
                model:model
            });
            self.$('.ui-inline-list').append(newUser.render().el);
        }

    });


    var numPeople = this.model.get('collaborators').models.length + this.model.get('project_manager').models.length - 6;
    console.log(numPeople);
    if(numPeople > 0) {
        self.$('.ui-inline-list').append('<li class="ui-inline-list__item"> + ' + numPeople + ' more</li>');
    }

    this.$el.attr('data-id', this.model.get('id'));
    this.$el.attr('data-organisationid', this.model.get('organisation_id'));

    if(this.model.get('archived_at') !== null) {
        this.$el.addClass('ui-list-block__item--archived');
        this.$el.addClass('ui-list-block__item--archived-' + parseInt(moment(this.model.get('archived_at'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY'), 10));
    }

    if( this.model.get('visible') == false ) {
        this.$el.hide();
    }

    if($('.ul-projects a[data-objectid="'+this.model.id+'"]').length < 1 ){

        this.$el.addClass('ui-list-block__item--closed');
    }

    return this;

}
```

The search is triggered in this view,

```
App.Views.GlobalSearch = Backbone.View.extend({

el : 'body',

template: _.template($('#tpl-global-search').html() ),

events: {
    "click .js-close-fullscreen" : "removeView",
    "click .js-make-filter" : "setSearchFilter",
    "click .js-trigger-search" : "doSearch",
    "keyup input[name=search]" : "processKey"
},

initialize: function() {

},

render: function() {
    this.$el.append(this.template());
    return this;
},

removeView: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.$('.ui-fullscreen').remove();
},

setSearchFilter: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var element = $(e.currentTarget);
    var selectedText = element.text();

    this.collectionName = element.data('collection');
    this.isArchived = element.data('archived');

    this.$('.dropdown-toggle').find('span:first').text(selectedText);
},

processKey: function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13){
        this.$('.js-trigger-search').trigger("click");
    }
},

doSearch: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = this;

    this.$('.global-search-container').removeClass('error').find('p').remove()

    if(this.collectionName == undefined) {
        this.collectionName = "ProjectSearch";
        this.isArchived = "all";
    }

    this.$('.js-trigger-search').find('i').removeClass('fa-search').addClass('fa-refresh spin')

    this.$('.ui-grid-list--results').empty();
    this.$('.ui-message-block').remove();

    var projects = App.Collections[this.collectionName];
    var findProjects = projects.search({ string: this.$('[name=search]').val(), archived: this.isArchived });  
    findProjects.done(function(projects){ 
        //console.log(projects) 
        var resultsView = new App.Views.GlobalResults({
            collection: projects
        });

        //resultsView.render();

        self.$('.js-trigger-search').find('i').removeClass('fa-refresh spin').addClass('fa-search')

    });

}
```

});

Now I have never used $.deferred or promise's before so it could be that I am using them wrong, but I dont think that is the case.

The search gets initialised simply with,

`var searchResults = new App.Views.GlobalResults;`

Comment: Where is your `.search()` method called?

Comment: Sorry, please see my edit @Roamer-1888

Comment: How many `.js-trigger-search` elements are there on the page?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 just the one. $('.js-trigger-search').length in my console returns 1

Comment: @Roamer I have figured it out the view is not being removed properly so the views event are still bound. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah OK. BTW, you can simplify the search function. `collection.fetch()` returns a jqXHR object, which is already a promise so you can purge the Deferred and all references to it, and simply `return collection.fetch(...).then(..., ...)`.